# SSH to backend app

Tags: python, linux, ssh, docker, scripting

I have a lot docker containers and my idea is to have one ssh server and when type `ssh <containerid>@myserver` it actually do `docker attach` to specific container. What I need is way how to after running someuser@host runs python script which make a tunnel to docker container. Same way git works using SSH.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to create those users either by script when creating the container or manually
and call your python script that do tunneling in the ~/.bashrc of the new user created. is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: @user6401364 technically yes, but how is that secure?

Comment: @hek2mgl because I do now want to login every time to server when I want to attach to container. Also, I dont want to give root SSH permissions to every developer.

Comment: I am not fully sure it will be secure since the may be able to escape the container . but I think I found solution for this. Make a script in your docker that will create new reverse proxy for each container created with different port. And since this port will forward all data directly to container you can ssh to it as you are sshing to the local container . you will need to handle authentication in the container in this case

Comment: If you want to virtualize *a server*, I would go for virtual machines rather than containers.